# Executing Aggregate framework query in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a console application which will read through a Mongo db and filter out some data based on some business logic and display the results on console screen.

Till now I am able to write the following query and execute it successfully on Mongo shell. Here is the query:

```
{db.Collection.aggregate([
{$unwind: { path: "$Pages"}},
{$group : {
  _id :{UrlPath: "$Pages.Url.Path", I_Id : "$_id", Date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d",date: "$Pages.DateTime"}}, CId: "$CId",
   x: {$sum:1},
   y : {$sum:"$V"}
 }},     
 {$group : {
   _id : {Date: "$_id.Date",CId: "$_id.CId", PageUrl: "$_id.UrlPath"},
    p: {$sum:1},
    q : {$sum:"$x"},
    TotalCount: {$sum:"$y"}
 }},
 {$sort:{p:-1}},     
],{allowDiskUse: true}).pretty();
};
```

The problem I am facing is replicating the same query logic in C# code. Till now I able to connect to mongo db collections and able to basic CRUD operations.

But replicating this aggregate logic is really blowing my mind. I have tried using PipelineDefinition option but can't manage to get correct output out of it.

Can some one please guide me in the correct direction here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to achieve it using collection.Aggregate() method.

Code looks like this:

```
collection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true})
                        .Unwind(i => i.Pages)
                        .Group(new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                               {
                                                   "_id", new BsonDocument 
                                                        {

                                                            { "Date", new BsonDocument("$dateToString", new BsonDocument {{"format", "%Y-%m-%d"}, {"date", "$Pages.DateTime"}})},                                                        
                                                            {"CId","$_id"}                                                                
                                                        }
                                               },
                                               {
                                                   "x", new BsonDocument
                                                        {
                                                            {"$sum", "$Value"}
                                                        }
                                               } 
                                        }
                                )
                          .Group(new BsonDocument
                                        {
                                               {
                                                   "_id", new BsonDocument 
                                                        {
                                                            {"Date", "$_id.Date"},
                                                            {"CId", "$_id.CId"}                                                           
                                                        }
                                               },
                                               {
                                                   "p", new BsonDocument
                                                        {
                                                            {"$sum", 1}
                                                        }                                                      
                                               },
                                               {
                                                   "q", new BsonDocument
                                                        {
                                                            {"$sum", "$x"}
                                                        }
                                               }
                                        }
                                 )
                            .Sort(new BsonDocument("q", -1))

                            .ToList();
```